# Django celery - Task results in Django Admin is empty

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have followed the tutorial to setup the celery/redis relevant settings. the celery task can run successfully, but the "Task results" in django admin is empty with 0 record.

here is my settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
result_backend = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'


CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"
# CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json', ]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

# celery setting.
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'default'

# # django setting.
# CACHES = {
#     'default': {
#         'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
#         'LOCATION': 'my_cache_table',
#     }
# }

CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30*60
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
app = Celery('mysite',backend='redis://localhost:6379/1', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings")
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.loader.override_backends['django-db'] = 'django_celery_results.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')



[2023-05-14 19:08:08,457: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: OnlinePricing.tasks.add[9c082207-ea07-4962-8bee-da3bce084564]
[2023-05-14 19:08:11,467: INFO/MainProcess] Task OnlinePricing.tasks.add[9c082207-ea07-4962-8bee-da3bce084564] succeeded in 3.0159999999996217s: 8
```

the above task results were never stored in the database I guess. I have migrate the django_celery_results. What's the underlying cause of this empty record problem?